# Bash backspace deleting one word at a time

Tags: keyboard, bash

There is a server at my work that uses csh as the default shell.
I prefer bash, so whenever I login, I start `bash`.

But for some reason, the backspace button deletes complete words instead of just deleting characters. Why is that? How do I change this and have the Bksp delete char by char??

FYI, Shift+Bksp deletes character by character. If possible, I'd like to have Shift+Bksp delete word by word. Only if possible.

Thanks

PS: Please don't tell me to hold the shift key; its downright annoying.

Comment: are you using putty or similar to connect, or is this from anouther nix machine ?

Comment: If you do `stty -a`, does the `erase` parameter say "^?". If you press Ctrl-v then Backspace, do you see "^?"? Another possibility you may see is "^H". What terminal software are you using? Does Backspace work normally in csh?

Comment: I would check the ˜/.bashrc or ˜/.bash_profile or the same files from /etc/skel if they don't exist in your home folder

Comment: @Sirex Yes, I'm using putty to connect. @Dennis yes, `stty -a` says `erase = ^?`. I'm using Putty. Yes, Bksp works okay with `csh`. Additionally, I see `werase = ^?` in `stty -a` output.

Comment: @Warnaud what would I check these files for? What am I looking for?

Comment: First look if they exist (the ˜/.bashrc and ˜/.bash_profile) rename them to see which one add this behaviour. If they don't exist, try commenting suspicious lines in /etc/bashrc or post them all here so we can look at them

Comment: Also, what is the OS on the server (output of `uname -mrs`)?

Comment: @Gilles By default `TERM` is set to `xterm`, but my `.bashrc` changes it to `ansi`, without any consequence. Output of `uname -mrs` is  `Linux 2.4.21-40.ELsmp i686`.

Answer (score 4):

Some terminals send `^h` (character number 8) for the <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> key, and some send `^?` (character number 127). Many terminal emulators can be configured, and most programs can be configured to know which key to expect. Obviously the two sides must agree.

Stty is a way in which applications can query the terminal's configuration. `erase = ^?` means that your terminal description file on the server claims that when your terminal sends `^?`, it means “erase the previous character”. `werase = ^?` means that `^?` means “erase the previous word”. There's a contradiction between these two settings.

When you log in over ssh, the ssh client sends a name for the terminal, which is put in the `TERM` environment variable. Programs on the server then look up descriptions of the terminal in a database (called termcap or terminfo). If these descriptions are broken, or if a configuration file somewhere (such as `/etc/profile` or `~/.login` or `~/.bashrc`) overrides the descriptions with wrong data, you might find that you have a mismatch. For example, one possible source for your problem is if some initialization file contains the command `stty werase '^?'` (forcing `^?` to mean a word erase) while your terminal sends `^?` for the backspace key.

Ideally, you should fix the conflict, as a lot of programs will read this information.

In Putty, you can configure which of `^?` or `^h` the <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> key sends. Check the value of this setting. Maybe the easiest way to fix your problem is to make Putty send `^h` for <kbd>BackSpace</kbd>, and make sure the server uses that setting (`stty erase '^h'`, to be put in `~/.bashrc`, will force it).

Comment: Why is it that csh runs okay, but bash has problems with this? When I run `stty -a` I see `erase` as well as `werase` set to '^?`. PS: I changed putty's backspace character to `^H` and backspace started working fine. But is there something I can put in .bashrc so I don't have to change putty's config?

Comment: @Here: Since there are contradictory indications about `^?`, it could be that csh just happens to read the terminal settings in a different order from bash. You can put `stty erase='^W'` (the usual setting) in your `.bashrc`, then you won't have contradictory settings any more and `^?` sent by `BackSpace` should erase a single character.