# Backspace deleting the entire line in terminal

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal

I have SSH'd into a gateway computer and then from there SSH'd into another computer. Every time I click on backspace the entire line gets deleted...

Using `stty -a` gives me the following (partial excerpt):

[image]

As you can see, backspace ("^?") is binded to `erase`, so I would expect using it to erase only a single character. Yet for some reason, it is behaving like ^U, where the entire line is deleted... As you can see below, as soon as I press backspace, the "^?" character is sent and the entire line is deleted despite it being mapped to `erase` not `kill`...

[image]

**There are many similar questions already posted but none of those solutions work here since stty already maps to `erase`**. (i.e. [this](https://superuser.com/questions/203383/bash-backspace-deleting-one-word-at-a-time))

I'm using bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in `intr = ^?`. When you hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, the shell receives `SIGINT` from the terminal and clears the command line. I can easily replicate the problem by running `stty intr ^?`.

Usually it's `intr = ^C`, which means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> triggers `SIGINT`. Run this:

```
stty intr ^C
```

Notes:

- In the above command you can type `^C` literally as two characters: `^` and `C`; `stty` should understand.
- To fix the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> it's enough to set `intr` to anything but `^?`. E.g. you can set it to nothing (undefined) by invoking `stty intr ''`. Still `^C` should be your first choice.